# Package dependency errors while installing mercurial in Fedora

Tags: fedora, mercurial, yum

I'm trying to install `mercurial` in my Fedora 14 using yum and get the following error.help to resolve this.

```
 yum --enablerepo=rpmforge --disablerepo=remi --disablerepo=fedora  install     mercurial.i386
 Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
 Adding en_US to language list
 Repository fedora is listed more than once in the configuration
 Repository updates is listed more than once in the configuration
 Setting up Install Process
 Resolving Dependencies
 --> Running transaction check
 ---> Package mercurial.i386 0:1.9.2-1.el5.rf set to be installed
 --> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: mercurial-1.9.2-1.el5.rf.i386
 --> Finished Dependency Resolution
 Error: Package: mercurial-1.9.2-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.7-8.fc14.1.i686 (@fedora/$releasever)
           python(abi) = 2.7
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove the RPMForge repository data permanently.** You should not be using a EL repo on a Feroda machine. Please mind the bitness of your operating system, `i686` means 32-bit. If you have a problem then log a bug in RH's Bugzilla requesting a version upgrade to the packages in the repository.

Comment: You mean disablerepo?

Comment: No, I mean remove it permanently. You should not be using a EL repo on a Fedora machine.

Comment: I've removed, but while yum list '*mercurial*' , I end up some .i686 only. mine is 32 bit

Comment: i686 is 32-bit.

Comment: ya am sorry, but I found 1.9 versions of mercurial in their website as source.  But the listed ones are 1.8, how to get the latest ones or should I install and update later

Comment: Log a bug in RH's Bugzilla requesting a version upgrade to the packages in the repo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1681/discussion-between-itsraja-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)